# Couldn't load SIP module. Python support will be disabled

Tags: python, qt

I installed QGIS version 3.6 on my pc with Lubuntu 18.10 64 bit.
I have python 3.6.7 and QT 5.11.1.

Once I run QGIS i get this error

```
 Couldn't load SIP module. Python support will be disabled.


    Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/qgis/__init__.py", line 72, in 
        from qgis.PyQt import QtCore   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/qgis/PyQt/QtCore.py", line 26, in 
        from PyQt5.QtCore import * ImportError: /home/giacomo/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/QtCore.so: symbol _ZN23QOperatingSystemVersion11MacOSMojaveE version Qt_5 not defined in file libQt5Core.so.5 with link time reference


    Python version:
    3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17)  [GCC 8.2.0]

    QGIS version:
    3.6.1-Noosa 'Noosa', 93e761d

    Python path: ['/usr/share/qgis/python', '/home/giacomo/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python', '/home/giacomo/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins', '/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins', '/usr/lib/python36.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.6', '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/home/giacomo/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

How can I install a SIP version running with my software?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem on Ubuntu 18.04 with QGIS-Madeira 3.4.13 after installing PyQt5. I didn't put it in virtual environment because I didn't anticipate there would be any issues; it must have overwritten PyQt4 and the older version of `sip`, as there is a special version associated with PyQt5. I was able to fix the issues with QGIS by uninstalling PyQt5's `sip` (and PyQt5, which could always be re-installed properly within a virtual environment), then re-installing `sip` system-wide (in the environment in which QGIS looks for it).

In the example below, I am making sure to use the Python 3 `pip` as I have both Python 2 and 3 on my system.

```bsh
sudo -H pip3 uninstall PyQt5-sip
sudo -H pip3 uninstall PyQt5

# This seems to be the Python package QGIS requires
sudo -H pip3 install sip
```